# AspNetCore AppSettings Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps to deploy our ASP.NET Core REST APIs. We currently store our settings in appSettings.json. We have multiple environments such as QA, PROD, DEV etc. Going from the best practices, we understand that we must not be checking in any appsettings files in source-control at all. That seems to make sense and we are moving into the Secrets manager.

However, we would love to see if there's a way we can take our settings (we have quite a few) from the appSettings.production.json for e.g. and somehow convert them into the format the Azure DevOps needs? -Setting "Value" seems to be the format. Because we have complex JSON nodes, we are now left with no choice but to laboriously take our JSON and flatten that into a series of settings with __ delimiters so that they can work correctly in our code.

Are we totally off with this approach? Is there a better way to do this? We are constantly having to manage our Prod JSON settings in a file and would love to automate the workflow to generate the DevOps compliant settings from the JSON.

Anyone have any ideas? Would love to hear how others are using the Azure DevOps to deploy their microservices, functions etc. to QA, Staging, Prod environments.

Thank you!

Comment: what confuses me is why or what are you putting in appsettings that is related to deployment. this part really confuses me. your question would be much better if you could put a sample YAML file here to see what you are doing and how. I hope you are not using the classic editor for devops.

Comment: if you really are putting devops things in app settings, then, yes, you have made a mistake there.

Comment: I think you may have not interpreted my question correctly. I am not putting DevOps settings in App Settings. I would like my App Settings to be deployed via DevOps. there's already a way to add these using a DevOps pipeline parameter, it just takes a very different format. I was wondering if there's a better way. Thank you!

Comment: its true, the way the question is framed confused me indeed. two solutions - azure key vault and secret variables, whichever makes more sense to your situation. these two solutions are so obvious, and your current devops deployment sounds so intricate - so you are clearly an advanced user of YAML, i did not think, this is what we are talking about :) my bad, my bad man :)

Comment: No problems at all. I am happy to get feedback! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should move your secret into Azure KeyVault and just keep name in your app config. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you have shown how you can do this.

If you need a fast win you may consider using [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) and move there you env configs and get them just before creating a package. However, this should not be your final solution, because you should have single package deployable to each env. How you can do this, as above. Use Key Vault with combination of Azure Configuration where you can override your settings value to indicate which Key Vault should be used on given environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I am looking at Azure Key Vault as an option. Here's a good article I found: https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/how-to-store-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-net-core